# Django - How to check if id contains in a table column?

Tags: python, django

guys.

I want to check in my django template, if **request.user** exists in some row of column user in my table **LeagueMember**. The way I found is not working.

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login/')
def search_leagues(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    return redirect('join_league')

leagues = League.objects.all()
return render(request, 'search_leagues.html', { 'allleagues': leagues })
```

model.py

```
class League(models.Model):
    league_owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    league_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def is_member(self):
        member = LeagueMember.objects.get(league=self)  
        if member:
            return True
        else:
            return False

class LeagueMember(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey('League', related_name='leaguemember_league')
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

search_leagues.html

```html
{% for league in allleagues %}
<tr>
   <td class="center">{{ league.league_name }}</td>
   <td class="center">{{ league.leaguemember_league.count}}/{{ league.leaguesettings_league.league_number_teams }}</td>
   <td class="center">{{ league.leaguesettings_league.league_eligibility }}</td>
   <td class="center">{{ league.leaguesettings_league.league_lifetime }}</td>
   {% if request.user in league.leaguemember_league.user %}
   DO SOMETHING!!!
   {% else %}
   {% if league.leaguemember_league.count < league.leaguesettings_league.league_number_teams %}
   {% if league.leaguesettings_league.league_eligibility == "Private" %}
   <form method="post" action="{% url 'joinleague' pk=league.id %}">
      <td class="center"><a href="{% url 'joinleague' pk=league.id %}" class="btn btn-mini btn-warning">Soliticar</a></td>
   </form>
   {% elif league.leaguesettings_league.league_eligibility == "Public" %}
   <form method="post" action="{% url 'joinleague' pk=league.id %}">
      <td class="center"><a href="{% url 'joinleague' pk=league.id %}" class="btn btn-mini btn-info">Entrar</a></td>
   </form>
   {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This error is in this line:

```
{% if request.user in league.leaguemember_league.user %}
```

Always goes to ELSE block

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

`league.leaguemember_league` will not give you a `LeagueMember` object but a [`RelatedManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager) object (so you cannot find a `user` property in it, therefore your template logic will not work).

What you are trying to do is go two levels deep in your relationship (`League` -> `LeagueMember` -> `User`). You can't easily do this kind of logic in your template and probably need to do it in your view code instead. For example:

```
league_data = []
for league in League.objects.all():
    league_data.append({
        'league': league,
        'users': User.objects.filter(leaguemember__league=league) # This gives you all the users that are related to this league
    })

 return render(request, 'search_leagues.html', { 'allleagues': league_data})
```

You then need to modify all your template logic to use this new structure:

```
{% for league_data in allleagues %}
# Replace league with league_data.league in all the template logic below this
```

In the `if` block you can then do:

```
{% if request.user in league_data.users %}
```

Note that this querying may not be very efficient if you have a large number of users/leagues - in which case you may need to rethink your model design.